# Angular 5 ngbPopover in a table does not display

Tags: angular5, ng-bootstrap

I'm not able to get my `ngbPopover` to show up in a table's `td` element.  I'm seeing lots of questions but no clear solution as to how to make this work in my Angular 5 application.

I can see that my method to return the popover text is being called, but the popover never actually appears.

Comment: I can put a popover just fine on `<td>` - see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/t727RTouBHXSkytzM7Zf?p=preview - can you modify this plunk to reproduce the case that is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Problem: I have got similar problem, My NgbPopover is in `<td>`, when I click, popover is not visible but dom expands.

Solution: What I figure out by inspecting element : find this element named "ngb-popover-window" and remove style property, and my popover is visible then. I don't know how to handle that in project, Probably overriding some css, I guess.

My Sample : removed style element from below shown code.

```
<ngb-popover-window role="tooltip" class="popover bs-popover-top" id="ngb-popover-0" style="top: 114px; left: 885px;">
```

Hope this helps!